# Декоратор на метод класса

Tags: python, декоратор

```
def auth_required(*scopes):
    def wrapper(handler):
        async def auth_md(request):
            payload = request.get('payload')
            if not payload:
                raise web.HTTPUnauthorized(reason='Authorization required')
        return auth_md
    return wrapper
```

Вот такой декоратор сооружаю - работает на функциях как надо, но вот на методах класса во внутреннюю функцию прилетает self.

Приходится переносить декоратор в роутер

```
web.get('/user', auth_required('admin')(auth.user))
```

Как переписать декоратор чтоб он работал и с методами и с функциями и при этом не усложнять кучей проверок что там на входе?

Через собачку вызывается `auth_md(self, request)`

```
class Auth:

   @auth_required('admin')
   async def user(self, request):
        ... = self...
        return
```

Comment: представьте пример кода где именно не работает..

Comment: @garrythehotdog ап

Answer (score 1):

Смею предположить, что вряд ли можно обойтись без проверки. Ведь в случае метода класса, у нас в любом случае будет передаваться в метод на одну переменную (`self`) больше, чем в функцию. И нам это место придется проверять. Если конечно этот метод у нас не `@staticmethod`. В этом случае декоратор заедет без дополнительных проверок. К тому же, я не встречал где-либо подобных декораторов, но это Имхо.

Как решение, могу предложить такую проверку:

```py
def auth_required(*scopes):
    def wrapper(handler):
        async def auth_md(*args):
            request = args[1] if len(args) > 1 else args[0]  # в методе класса args = (obj_Class, request), в функции args = (request)
            payload = request.get('payload')
            if not payload:
                raise web.HTTPUnauthorized(reason='Authorization required')
        return auth_md
    return wrapper
```

Comment: по количеству аргументов не уверен. боюсь поменяют гдето апи аргумент на кейворд

Comment: ++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 1):

Если вы уверены, что всегда будет один параметр, то можно обойтись без проверки

```
def auth_required(*scopes):
def wrapper(handler):
    async def auth_md(*args):
        request = args[-1]
        payload = request.get('payload')
        if not payload:
            raise web.HTTPUnauthorized(reason='Authorization required')
    return auth_md
return wrapper
```

если не уверены - то решение предыдущего автора надо дполнить ключевыми параметрами

```
def auth_required(*scopes):
def wrapper(handler):
    async def auth_md(*args, **kwargs):
        request = args[1] if len(args) > 1 else args[0]  # в методе класса args = (obj_Class, request), в функции args = (request)
        payload = request.get('payload')
        if not payload:
            raise web.HTTPUnauthorized(reason='Authorization required')
    return auth_md
return wrapper
```

Ваше возражение "*по количеству аргументов не уверен. боюсь поменяют гдето апи аргумент на кейворд*"  неуместно, т.к. даже в примере с функцией любое из названных вами изменений потребует переписывания декоратора.
Изменят  -  перепишите декоратор.

Ну и да - рекомендую пользоваться встроенным модулем.

```
from functools import wraps
```